# First state is empty, and second is never properly re-rendered?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-state, react-state-management

I'm having trouble with the following block of code. I'm trying to get my "announcements" to render once they have been fetched from the server. The initial state is empty, and updates after ComponentDidMount() (I have console.logged and see that it does indeed work). However, my renderAnnouncements() never re-renders with this new fetched data, so Announcements just stays empty. Any help is appreciated!

```
import axios from "axios";
import { Container, Table, Button, Row, Col } from "react-bootstrap";
import Header from "../../../components/Header";
import AnnouncementModal from "./AnnouncementModal";
import ResourceModal from "./ResourceModal";
import CourseModal from "./CourseModal";

class CourseEditorDetail extends React.Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);

    this.state = {
      isLoading: false,
      announcements: [],
    };
  }

  getCourseAnnouncements = async () => {
    const url =
      "https:url/api/announcement/read_course.php?course_id=" +
      this.props.match.params.id;

    axios.get(url).then((response) => {
      this.setState({ announcements: response.data.records });
    });
  };

  componentDidMount = async () => {
    this.setState({ isLoading: true });
    await this.getCourseAnnouncements();
    this.setState({ isLoading: false });
  };

  renderAnnouncements = () => {
    const { announcements, editAnnounceModalShow } = this.state;

    announcements.map((a) => {
      return (
        <tr key={a.id}>
          <td>
            <b>{a.subject}</b>
            <br />
            {a.content}
          </td>
          <td>
            <Button onClick={this.handleEditAnnounceModalShow}>Edit</Button>
            <AnnouncementModal
              subject={a.subject}
              content={a.content}
              course_id={a.course_id}
              show={editAnnounceModalShow}
              handleModalClose={this.handleEditAnnounceModalClose}
              isEditing={true}
            />
          </td>
        </tr>
      );
    });
  };

  render() {
    const {
      code,
      name,
      subject,
      semester,
      year,
      id,
      isLoading,
      announcements,
    } = this.state;

    return (
      <div>
        {isLoading && <div>LOADING</div>}
        {!isLoading && (
          <div>
            <Header title="Course" />
            <Container>
              <h3>Announcements</h3>
              <Table>
                <thead>
                  <tr>
                    <th>Announcement</th>
                    <th>Date</th>
                    <th></th>
                  </tr>
                </thead>
                <tbody>{this.renderAnnouncements()}</tbody>
              </Table>
              <Button onClick={this.handleCreateAnnounceModalShow}>
                Add announcement
              </Button>
              <AnnouncementModal
                show={createAnnounceModalShow}
                handleModalClose={this.handleCreateAnnounceModalClose}
                isEditing={false}
              />
            </Container>
          </div>
        )}
      </div>
    );
  }
}

export default CourseEditorDetail;
```

Answer (score 0):

You have to return the result from the map function in the `renderAnnouncements`  function.
currently, it is returning undefined